# Possibilities of Hadoop with MSSQL Reporting

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, hbase, azure-hdinsight

I have been evaluating Hadoop on azure HDInsight to find a big data solution for our reporting application. The key part of this technology evaluation is that the I need to integrate with MSSQL Reporting Services as that is what our application already uses. We are very short on developer resources so the more I can make this into an engineering exercise the better. What I have tried so far

- Use an ODBC connection from MSSQL mapped to the Hive on HDInsight.
- Use an ODBC connection from MSSQL using HBASE on HDInsight.
- Use SPARKQL locally on the azure HDInsight Remote desktop

What I have found is that HBASE and Hive are far slower to use with our reports. For test data I used a table with 60k rows and found that the report on MSSQL ran in less than 10 seconds. I ran the query on the hive query console and on the ODBC connection and found that it took over a minute to execute. Spark was faster (30 seconds) but there is no way to connect to it externally since ports cannot be opened on the HDInsight cluster.

Big data and Hadoop are all new to me.  My question is, am I looking for Hadoop to do something it is not designed to do and are there ways to make this faster?I have considered caching results and periodically refreshing them, but it sounds like a management nightmare. Kylin looks promising but we are pretty married to windows azure, so I am not sure that is a viable solution.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to replace SQL Server with Hadoop? What is not working in the current implementation?

Comment: @marek This is a "top Down" request in the company that I do not want to go into here. Essentially, we are looking for very low latency reporting solution for large data sets. Concerning the Cloudera distribution installation, I was under the impression that this would not work due to the limitation of ports on HDInsight clusters.  http://goo.gl/EeKvdX. Also what would be the advantage, if any, to utilizing Impala over Tez?

Comment: Hive is suitable for complex, long-running queries (think ETL or recommendation engines), not reporting. It uses MapReduce under the hood. Hive-on-Tez or Hive-on-Spark will be faster, but with no hands-on experience I am not competent to recommend either.

Comment: No Azure experience here but Cloudera can be installed from the Marketplace http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/cloudera/clouderaenterprise/. It's a pre-production release, so it must be something new.

Comment: I mentioned Impala, because I use it. It's not perfect but it is fast. Download a Cloudera QuickStart VM, run it on your laptop, load the test dataset and you will be able to compare Hive and Impala.

Comment: Marek, thank you for the information. In your experience is Impala fast enough to use for real time reporting?

Comment: That depends. How much data? How many nodes in the cluster? How complex are the reports? Will SSRS push down the processing to Impala or try to fetch all data to process it itself? Does Impala include all the functions you need (for example, statistical functions may be missing)? Do you need full Unicode support?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this documentation on optimizing Hive queries: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-optimize-hive-query/

Specifically look at ORC and using Tez. I would create a cluster that has Tez on by default and then store your data in ORC format. Your queries should be much more performant then.

Answer (score 0):

If going through Spark is fast enough, you should consider using the [Microsoft Spark ODBC driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47713). I am using it and the performance is not comparable to what you'll get with MSSQL, other RDBMS or something like ElasticSearch but it does work pretty reliably.